# PHP get next day name in array if current day name is not exists

Tags: php, arrays

Please help me, I have $repeatdays array `$repeatdays = ['sunday', 'monday', 'tuesday', 'wednesday', 'thursday', 'friday', 'saturday']`,

I do this to get next day name:

```
$current = 'wednesday';
$keys = array_values($repeatdays);
$ordinal = (array_search($current,$keys)+1)%count($keys);
$nextreccurence = strtolower($keys[$ordinal]);
echo $nextreccurence; // will return 'thursday'
```

but what if `'wednesday'` is not exist in `$repeatdays`? for example `$repeatdays = ['sunday', 'monday', 'tuesday', 'thursday', 'friday', 'saturday']`
I do this again:

```
$current = 'wednesday';
$keys = array_values($repeatdays);
$ordinal = (array_search($current,$keys)+1)%count($keys);
$nextreccurence = strtolower($keys[$ordinal]);
echo $nextreccurence; // but now only return 'monday', my expected result 'thursday'
```

how I can get expected `'thursday'` result if `'wednesday'` is not exist in that array?

====
by the way, `$repeatdays` is dynamic by user selected day that stored into `$repeatdays`.
for example if today is `'wednesday'` then user selected is `['sunday', 'friday']`, then I want system to get `'friday'`,

AND if today is `'friday'` then user selected is `['sunday', 'friday']`, then I want system to get `'sunday'`,

Comment: Why wouldn't it exist? What is the role of this array?

Comment: Do you have to use this array, or can you also use built in php functionalities?

Comment: just in case, for reccuring day per-weeks like google calendar @ZoliSzabó

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution would be to have a second, reference array with all the days, where you could look up next days until you'll find one that is available also in `$repeatdays`.

One not perfect implementation would be:

```php
<?php

function get_next_day($current)
{
    $reference = ['sunday', 'monday', 'tuesday', 'wednesday', 'thursday', 'friday', 'saturday'];
    $current_key = array_search($current, $reference);
    $next_key = ($current_key + 1) % count($reference);
    return $reference[$next_key];
}

function search_for_available_next_day($current, $repeatdays)
{
    $next = $current;
    do {
        $next = get_next_day($next);
    }
    while (!in_array($next, $repeatdays));
    return $next;
}

var_dump(search_for_available_next_day('wednesday', ['sunday', 'friday']));
var_dump(search_for_available_next_day('friday', ['sunday', 'friday']));
var_dump(search_for_available_next_day('thursday', ['sunday', 'friday']));
var_dump(search_for_available_next_day('saturday', ['sunday', 'friday']));
```

Comment: nice, this is what I want. thanks @ZoliSzabó

Answer (score 0):

If you can use the php functions, then you can do this:

```
$dayoftheweek = "wednesday"; // or however you populate it
$timestampday = strtotime($dayoftheweek);

echo date('l', strtotime("+1 day", $timestampday));
```